# Understanding Asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am learning `asyncio` in python and I have a trivial example:

```
async def main():
    print('start task')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    task = asyncio.create_task(do_something("washing dishes"))
    print('end task')  


async def do_something(text):
    print(f'Doing {text}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'Done {text}')


asyncio.run(main())
```

I don't understand why it prints

```
start task
end task
Doing washing dishes
```

and never prints `Done washing dishes`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does asyncio.create\_task not run the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57630209/why-does-asyncio-create-task-not-run-the-method)

Answer (score 0):

You should await the task to make sure the main coroutine waits for it to complete.

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('start task')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    task = asyncio.create_task(do_something("washing dishes"))
    await task  # Wait for the task to complete
    print('end task')

async def do_something(text):
    print(f'Doing {text}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'Done {text}')

asyncio.run(main())
```

OUTPUT:

```
start task
Doing washing dishes
Done washing dishes
end task
```

Comment: So "Done washing dishes" was never printed because the program exited before the task can finish?

Comment: Yes @alexwbt , that's correct. The 'Done washing dishes' message was not printed because the main coroutine, which is the entry point of the program, exited before the 'do_something' task could complete. When using 'asyncio.create_task', it launches the task in the background, and if the main coroutine completes before the task finishes, the program may exit, potentially leaving the task unfinished.

Comment: @TheHungryCub is it correct to say that when do_something runs in the background, a subprocess is created from the main process main is running on?

Comment: @Frustrated_coder, No, in the context of asyncio in Python, the do_something coroutine does not create a subprocess. Instead, it is running asynchronously within the same event loop as the main coroutine.
When you use asyncio.create_task(do_something("washing dishes")) in the main coroutine, it creates a task that runs the do_something coroutine concurrently with the main coroutine. However, both coroutines are executed within the same Python process and share the same event loop.

Comment: @Frustrated_coder,  Asyncio uses a single-threaded event loop to manage the execution of asynchronous coroutines. It allows tasks to run concurrently by suspending and resuming their execution as needed, but all of this happens within the same process.

Comment: @TheHungryCub when we use await we essentially tell the main coroutine to wait for the task to finish right? if so, isn't that blocking?

Comment: @Frustrated_coder When you use await, you are not blocking the entire program or the main coroutine. Instead, you are suspending the execution of the current coroutine until the awaited task (or coroutine) completes. During this suspension, the event loop is free to execute other coroutines or tasks.