# Pass return value from coroutine to callback function without using await

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

```py
import asyncio

async def f():
    # something, for example await asyncio.sleep(4)
    return "return value from f"

async def main():
    # schedule f, print result, but don't await
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # just an example for some other task
        print(i)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I could use `print(await f())` but that blocks due to `await`. I want `print` to be called as a "callback function" after `f()` has returned while the rest of `main()` has already continued. So, assuming that `# something` in `f` took 4 seconds, the expected output would look like this:

```
0
1
2
3
return value from f
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: You probably have a few options. [`add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback), [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), and [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) come to mind. Without knowing more specifics, though, it's hard to say which will work best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that takes `f` and a callback function as parameters.

```
async def call(f, cb):
    cb(await f())
```

And you can schedule a task for it without using await:

```
asyncio.create_task(call(f, print))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I changed the f() coroutine a little bit but this does seem to work. Also, you need to await asyncio.sleep(). Let me know what you think or if you have any questions.

Here's the answer that I referenced: [How I call an async function without await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630676/how-i-call-an-async-function-without-await)

```
import asyncio

async def f():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("return value from f")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(f())
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # just an example for some other task
        print(i)

asyncio.run(main())
```