# How can I start an asynchronous task with "create_task" and not wait until it is done?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run a `while True` loop with asyncio.

```
import asyncio

async def cpu_bound_task():
    something that take long time
    return result

async def post_result_from_cpu_bound_task(res):
    _loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    post_res = await _loop.run_in_executor(
        None,
        request.post,
        end_point,
        data
    )

async def main():
    while True:
        cpu_task = asyncio.create_task(cpu_bound_task())
        res = await cpu_task
        post_result_task = asyncio.create_task(post_result_from_cpu_bound_task(res))
        r = await post_result_task

asyncio.run(main())
```

What I expect is

1. do cpu task
2. and it return result as res
3. pass res to coroutine that post res
4. while posting the res do cpu task asynchronously
5. when cpu task is done, the post task that run asynchronously with cpu task would be done too
6. go to phase 2

but its actual workflow is

1. do cpu task
2. and it return result as res
3. pass res to coroutine that post res
4. post task is done
5. go to phase 1

The Python version I'm using is 3.10.

Comment: Your code `r = await post_result_task`  quite literally means "post task is done; go to phase 1". So don't wait for `post_result_task` to be done by removing `await post_result_task`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call an async function without await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630676/how-can-i-call-an-async-function-without-await)

Comment: @mkrieger1
I remove the code line that you said 
with adding print("would this really be executed?") in post function

and when I run that there was not any error with printing "would this really be executed?"

and I realize that I really don't know about async/await

so would you share any document that explain await well? 

besides, if I want the result from request.post, what should I do?